# Parse push issue

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using parse rest api from my php app to push to ios app. I can see in parse it has been pused to parse successfully

[image]

But how come parse not pushing these notificatioin to ios app?

Comment: Show your REST API code.

Comment: The segment you were sending to didn't match any devices. I'm assuming you have devices correctly registered, yeah? Take a look at the parameters you were using to query the segment, that should show you why its sending to 0 devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following the below steps:-

1) Register for remote notification from iOS app `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

2) Subscribe the UDID to channels - Group channels as per your requirement

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:@"ChannelName" forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

3) Send Notification to the particular channel from your php app.